# Tailwind css fixed width not working with other element in flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, tailwind-css

I have to place two column side by side. One of these columns has a fixed width. I am really trying hard to understand why the fixed width in one column is not working on Tailwind CSS flexbox.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="flex flex-row justify-between items-start shrink-0">
    <p class="mt-4 h-14 overflow-hidden leading-7">This title pushed back the next element</p>
    <div class="p-1 w-16 h-16 text-white text-center">
        <p class="text-sm">05</p>
        <p class="text-3xl leading-none font-bold">JUNE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tailwind Version: 3.0.23

Output:

[image]

Inspect Element:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: You may add 'flex-shrink-0' to an element with fixed width

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka you saved my day. Would you please post as an answer so that I can accept that for future reader, even me :)

Answer (score 12):

Actually when using `flex` , it shrinks itself if not explicitly specified for responsive design

Refer the tailwind flex-shrink documentation https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-shrink

It says to use the `flex-shrink-0` css property i.e `shrink-0` class to avoid the width from being shrinked due to variable width size.

So code should look like:

```
<div className="flex flex-row justify-between items-start">
      <p className="mt-4 h-14  overflow-hidden leading-7">
        This title pushed back the next element and this is the long text to
        check the overflow of the text and lets see if this actually works
      </p>
      <div className="p-1 w-16 h-16 text-white text-center shrink-0 bg-purple-500">
        <p class="text-sm">JUN</p>
        <p class="text-3xl leading-none font-bold">05</p>
      </div>
```

And the output looks like :

[image]

Comment: Note that "flex-shrink-0" is only for tailwind v2, "shrink-0" is the updated class in tailwind version 3

Comment: yeah class is "shrink-0" that gets converted into css property "flex-shrink-0"

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="flex flex-row justify-between items-start shrink-0">
    <p class="mt-4 h-14 w-[70%] overflow-hidden leading-7">This title pushed back the next element</p>
    <div class="p-1 w-[15%] h-16 text-white text-center">
        <p class="text-sm">05</p>
        <p class="text-3xl leading-none font-bold">JUNE</p>
    </div>
</div>
Maybe like this work
```

Comment: I need an actual width for the right section, and as because % will act differently in responsive view, this is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `flex properties` here while keeping the width same.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex flex-row justify-between items-start ">
    <div>
    <p class="py-2 px-2 h-14 overflow-hidden leading-6">This title pushed back the next element
       his title pushed back the next element.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="px-2 w-16 h-16 mr-2 text-white bg-purple-500 text-center">
        <p class="text-sm">June</p>
        <p class="text-3xl leading-none font-bold">05</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some of the rules were working but some of the ones with prefixes such as `lg:flex` and `lg:w-72` were not getting picked up. My problem was I reorganized using the new [app router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing) and I forgot to update my `tailwind.config.js` to include that path.

I changed:

```
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
```

to this:

```
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
```

and it worked!